# Using JEST to run Angular component test gives cannot find module

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

Using Jest for the first time. Used the following code to initialze a component testing:

```
describe('CreateComponent', () => {
  let component: CreateQuoteComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CreateQuoteComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ CreateQuoteComponent ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateQuoteComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));

  test('should exist', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

When running, for some of the imports in the component gives

```
Test suite failed to run Cannot find module' with ' 
at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/modules/xxx/components/landing/create/create.component.ts:19:1)
```

any leads for this or is there known workaround?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured the issue out. Seems JEST cannot resolve relative paths that we configure inside the app like '@' signs so we need to provide the jest moduleNameMapper like below:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/jest.ts",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@oshc(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/modules/oshc/$1",
      "@shared(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/app/@shared/$1"
    }
```

},

**UPDATE** : There will be another problem of JEST cannot find modules inside node_modules of your root folder. For this add the follwoing to jest configuration for module directories :
"moduleDirectories": [
"node_modules",
"src"
]

Answer (score 4):

In my case I changed the absolute path to the relative path and it worked.
The change must be made in both component.ts and spec.ts files

For example, use this import:

```
import { GenericService } from '../../../shared/services/generic.service';
```

Instead of:

```
import { GenericService } from 'src/app/shared/services/generic.service';
```

Comment: I confirm that worked also for me. But the question is why? However, I would like to use absolute paths